# Unable to install Remote Desktop Session Host role on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am unable to install Remote Desktop Session Host role while trying to setup a remote app on a virtual machine. It asks for a restart after completing the installation wizard but reverts back to the same state after the pending restart. Can't find any exception log file either (at %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\ServerManager\ServerManagerExceptions.log). Any suggestions would be helpful.

Note:

1. A licensing server is also configured on the same virtual machine.
2. It installs just fine on a Windows Server 2012 R2 virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar issue.   In my case I had partially disabled the firewall on the server.   Re-enabling the full firewall, running the install, then disabling again worked.